# Uninitialized variable using IIFE and fold expression in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, iife, parameter-pack, fold-expression

I was playing around with IIFE's and parameter packs in MSVC C++20 when I stumbled across a strange error. The following code is a minimal reproducible example.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
    std::function<void(Ts...)> fnc = {};
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&) : fnc(
        [](Ts... ts) {
            bool test = ([&ts](){ return true; }() && ...);
            std::cout << test << std::endl;
        }
    ) {}
};
int main() {
    Foo<int> f;
    Foo<int> f2 = f;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error(s):

```
error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'test' used
fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
```

which does not make sense to me. What's even more strange is that making the copy constructor a default constructor gets rid of the error. Should this be the case, or is there a bug in the compiler?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What compilation flags? Please post the full error message instead of describing it.

Comment: Probably a MSVC bug. Both GCC and Clang compile this just fine.

Comment: "_the following error_": It is not an error, just a warning. MSVC still compiles the code. The warning is a false positive. I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry for being unclear. It follows up with a LINK error, which I have now added.

Comment: @BubLblckZ It links fine on compiler explorer as well (note that I enabled Output... -> Link to binary) https://godbolt.org/z/q8jTTf7d3. There should be another error message from the linker if linking fails. C4700 is from the compilation step.

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using?  I only get this error in godbolt.

Comment: msvc 19.latest gives the warning but msvc 19.35 doesn't...

Comment: @user17732522 True; after removing some flags I originally used it does build with only the warning, however, the program behaves as if the variable is actually uninitialized, so there still seems to be a bug there. In older versions of MSVC there is no bug though, so probably just a bug in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Uniform initialization appears to not trigger the warning

```
bool test{ ([&ts](){ return true; }() && ...) };
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8fvfnsfh1

Edit:  Still gives the wrong result on MSVC 19.36

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although this makes even less sense, it does seem to fix the error, so thanks!

Comment: @BubLblckZ Switching to msvc 19.35 in godbolt seems to fix it too, I can't get the warning to trigger in VS2022.

Comment: @Rlyeh Yep, thanks for the help, seems to be a bug in the latest version of msvc.

Comment: @BubLblckZ Just checked it out and my solution gives the wrong results in the latest version.